# System.AnsiToUtf8 does not convert

Tags: delphi, utf-8

I would like to convert some Strings into their UTF-8 representation. For that task i tried the function `System.AnsiToUtf8` that is decladed as follows:

```
function AnsiToUtf8(const S: string): _RawByteStr;
begin
  Result := Utf8Encode(S);
end;
```

This worked for me for quite a while until i discovered, that this function is not doing what i expect it to do all times.

For looking a little deeper into this, i isolated this routine into my own function `MyAnsiToUtf8`:

```
function MyAnsiToUtf8(S: string): RawByteString;
begin
  Result := System.AnsiToUtf8(S);
end;
```

It produces the same results like the function `System.AnsiToUtf8`.

So when i make a call like this: `LabeledEdit2.Text := String(MyAnsiToUtf8('äöü'));` then the resulting "LabeledEdit2.Text" holds the same characters (äöü). It doesn't matter if i call this function with a direkt parameter like above or with some string variable containing the umlaut-characters.

So i played around a little and finally discovered a solution that is really puzzling me!

```
function MyAnsiToUtf8(S: string): RawByteString;
begin
  Result := 'x' + System.AnsiToUtf8(S);
  delete(Result, 1, 1)
end;
```

How come, that the above code produces the correct result (Ã¤Ã¶Ã¼)?

Another question is: why doesn't the first call give me the correct result?

Comment: Thank You for your reply! It all sounds logical to me and i really hoped that that would be the answer... but its not. I will stick to my funny solution from above - although it looks like an side effect to me.

Comment: Very hard to see Ã¤Ã¶Ã¼ as the "correct" solution to any problem. This is what you get when you do it wrong. Also do bear in mind that you have something that is dependent on some choice of ANSI encoding. Which ANSI encoding is it. Do you know?

Comment: Yes, for me that is the correct solution. I need nothing else but pure and reliable encoded utf-8 characters. Usually i don't display them but write them to a memory stream or save them to a file. i am building xml, html and e-mail from this.

Comment: It's the wrong solution. What you actually want are UTF8 bytes. We can help you with that.

Comment: @Wittenborner `Ã¤Ã¶Ã¼` is NOT "reliable encoded utf-8".  It is the *ANSI/Latin representation* of the UTF-8 encoding of `äöü`. Two different things. I think you are getting confused about what you think you need and what you actually need.

Comment: What you want is TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes

Answer (score 3):

`LabeledEdit2.Text` is a `UnicodeString`. You are converting a UTF-16 `UnicodeString` to a UTF-8 `RawByteString`, and then converting that `RawByteString` back to a UTF-16 `UnicodeString`. All of those conversions are lossless, so of course you end up with the same Unicode characters you started with.

If you really want a UTF-8 encoded string, then you don't need to use `System.AnsiToUtf8()` at all. You can simply use the `UTF8String` type instead, and assign your `UnicodeString` directly to it. The RTL will handle the conversion to UTF-8 for you.

If you want to see the UTF-8 bytes, don't display the UTF-8 string as-is in a UI that expects a `UnicodeString`, as that will convert the data to UTF-16. Instead, you should hex-encode the bytes before displaying them, or write the bytes to a file, etc.

Your "funny solution" doesn't actually return a UTF-8 string at all. Yes, `System.AnsiToUtf8()` returns a UTF-8 string (actually, a `RawByteString` with the `CP_UTF8` codepage assigned to it), but when you concatenate that string with the `'x'` literal, you are creating a new `RawByteString` that has **lost the UTF-8 codepage**! It uses your OS's default codepage instead (you can verify that with `System.StringCodePage()` to see which codepage is actually assigned to each string). When you then convert that new `RawByteString` to `UnicodeString`, the RTL uses your OS codepage to convert the bytes to UTF-16. And that is why you are seeing the UTF-8 bytes being displayed as `Ã¤Ã¶Ã¼` instead of `äöü` - the bytes were **misinterpreted** as ANSI/Latin, not as UTF-8, during the conversion to UTF-16.

IOW, `äöü` is encoded in UTF-8 as bytes `C3 A4 C3 B6 C3 BC`, and that same byte sequence interpreted as Latin-1 or similar is characters `Ã¤Ã¶Ã¼`.

DO NOT use `RawByteString` the way you are using it. It was never meant to be used as a function return value, only as a function input parameter. But, if you must use it as a return value, then you need to use `System.SetCodePage()` to assign the correct codepage to the `RawByteString` to avoid data loss at the caller side.

Otherwise, in this situation, just use `UTF8String` instead, as it does exactly what you need, with no surprises.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the details! You pointed out, that i am loosing the UTF-8 codepage. To me that sounds good! i need thoose plain utf-8 coded string to build my xml and html files. Also i use this for utf-8 encoded e-mails. i will check into the usage of RawByteString again. I could use TBytes instead but a Byte-String better fits my needs. Thanks again!

Comment: "*i am loosing the UTF-8 codepage. To me that sounds good*" - If that is what you think, then you have a fundamental misunderstanding of how UTF-8 and HTML/XML actually work. You should not be using `RawByteString` at all. You should be using `(Unicode)String` in memory, and only convert to UTF-8 at the last possible point where data actually leaves your app (eg, when saving a file, or when transmitting an email, etc).